# Unable to tap on Button inside a Notification with ProgressBar

Tags: android, button, notifications, progress-bar, action

```
Intent intentCancel = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
intent.putExtra(MainActivity.UPLOAD_CANCELED, true);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(Service.this, 0, intentCancel, 0);
builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(Service.this);
builder.setOngoing(true);
builder.setContentTitle("Uploading");
builder.addAction(R.mipmap.ic_ab_close, "Cancel", pendingIntent);
builder.setProgress(100,0, false); 
notificationManager.notify(idNotification, builder.build());
```

This is my code to create a Notification. This will be updated acoording to a HTTP Request that uploads a file to my webserver. This is the progress callback method:

```
public void progress(int current, int total) {
    if (notificationManager != null && builder != null) {
        builder.setProgress(total, current, false);
        notificationManager.notify(idNotification, builder.build());
    }
}
```

**The problem is:** When that progressbar is being updated fast as file upload, I can **not** tap on Cancel button.

Should be the **upload method is so fast** than the notification keep always reconstructing, this way **tapping is never enabled**?

*P.S.: When progress finishes, cancel button is "tappable".*

What could I do to fix that?

**Related questions:**

[Android notification progressbar freezing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6390016/android-notification-progressbar-freezing?rq=1)

[Huge memory usage in notifications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3608684/huge-memory-usage-in-notifications)

Comment: Solution is delay the progress update: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28336857/406110.